# Can I use trilinear filtering for my sprites, but keep their outlines unfiltered?

Tags: unity, 2d, textures, sprites, filtering

Suppose that I have two images of equal size. They both contain a square:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI62X.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nev5Z.png

When overlapped, both squares will appear next to each other.

If both images use `Point (no filter)`, they will contact without issues regardless of the amount of zoom or scale:

[image]

If you use either `Bilinear` or `Trilinear`, there will be an artifact visible in certain zoom/scale levels:

[image]

Of course, that is to be expected from the very nature of the filters. As much as I would like to just leave it at `Point (no filter)`, my game looks far better using `Trilinear` instead - except of course, for the "borders" or points of contact.

The ideal scenario for me as bizarre as it may sound, is to be able to use `Trilinear` filtering generally, but force the "outlines" of my sprites to stay as if they were `Point (no filter)`. This way, my game looks painterly when zoomed in/out (the game isn't pixel art), and I also avoid the "glitch" in specific contacts.

---

- Yes, the glitch is only noticeable if you use a scale/zoom that is higher than 100%. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the game, the player should be able to zoom in/out if they desire, so I can't just pick "the" ideal camera size or sprite scale because it can't be constant.
- I've tried using `Canvas` and its `Pixel Perfect` checkbox to no avail. I didn't really expect that to work though.

---

What can I do to achieve the desired effect, then?